# Authorize an user to use a permission-required software downloaded in program file(x86)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, authorization

There are several permission-required software downloaded in **program file(x86)** in my company. Every time users need to use them, I have to go to their computers and type the password of administrator for them.

This is okay, but there's a user needs to use a software many times everyday. Thus I decide to authorize him or his computer to use the software without permission.

My company uses windows server 2012 r2, I'm not sure how the software are restricted.
My supervisor said when a software could add or modify information in program file(x86) need to permitted by administrator.

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If a UAC prompt is requesting administrative credentials to execute the application, this would not have anything to do with your WS2012 server, rather it's the application being executed that is asking for this.

There are two ways around this. The first one requires you to give the users local administrator rights on the workstations.

What you would need to do, is:

1. Create a security group within your AD environment, and assign all users to that group.
2. On each computer that needs administrative privileges to run the application, open Computer Management, and add the group created to the Local Administrators group.
3. Restart the PC to ensure that the new group has indeed been added to the Local Administrators group.

You can also create a shortcut to the application with the following parameters:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:domain\username /savecreds "C:\fakepath\program.exe"
```

For the /user switch, enter the credentials that you want to run the application as (I would recommend a local administrative account) in the format [COMPUTER]\[USER]. When you first execute the shortcut, it will prompt for the user's password and should then store it for future use, no longer requiring it for each subsequent execution. Make sure the /savecreds switch is included and the path to the application is enclosed in quotes.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/dfa11529-528d-4eb5-a8c7-d2b7fad4058b/how-to-setup-shortcut-to-always-run-as-different-user?forum=w7itproui

There is also an application you can use called [RunAsTool](https://www.sordum.org/8727/runastool-v1-4/) which will allow you to store administrative credentials for applications to use to run.

Comment: Thanks for  you reply. I've tried both ways.

1. I don't know why It doesn't work, also, my supervisor doesn't want the users to be local admin.

2. It works on most applications but not that one...

My supervisor wants me to give the permission of the folder of the app in programfile(x86) to the user.

Comment: Can the user browse to the folder in which the executable is located?

Comment: Yes, he can.
I'm wondering that maybe the reason why the app needs authorization is because that it needs to use hardware or firmware.
But I still can't figure out how to deal with that.

Comment: Ok, it does not sound like a file permissions problem (because they can see it and unless someone has changed permissions they can also execute), it sounds like it is User Account Control. It is not a issue, rather it is by design. I've updated my answer with another solution.